# Silverlight usercontrol movement with mouse

Tags: silverlight, user-controls, mousemove

I am trying to create a control that allows capture of a still image from a streaming network cam. My idea is to stream the camera into a rectangle control, which I have functioning. I need to provide ability for user to specify area of the stream they want to capture. For this I have created a very simple UserControl with a grid having 2xcolumns and rows and setting ShowGridLines to true.

I show this in the same grid column/row as my streaming Rectangle and can see my "crosshairs" in the centre of my stream. I now need to position the centre of my UserControl to the mouse cursor co-ordinates.

Can anyone help as I'm struggling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add EventTrigger for `MouseLeftButtonUp` and within it use `Point position = e.GetPosition(null);`. After this manipulation you'll have mouse position and can do whatever you need with `UserControl`.

Comment: Thanks for response. I have the mouse x&y captured with code you describe, my problem is that the view model that is capturing the x&y has no concept of the view therefore doesn't know about the usercontrol. I'm struggling what properties of my usercontrol to bind to these x&y values???????

Comment: You can calculate x&y coordinates of your Control according to the cursor position and bind this values to control's x&y values.

Comment: I have this working with a simple textBlock as a Canvas child. The textBlock follows my cursor as I require but when I drop my userControl in the Canvas it does not appear, am I missing a trick here?

Comment: D'oh, probably helps if I set the minwidth/height of my usercontrol doesn't it :-( What a clown. Cheers for your pointer anatolliG.